# Angular 5 Snapshot Ip camera

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, camera, ip

how could pass the scripts tags to angular 5 component? 
i could put this  tags working on normal .html page but to work on angular 5 component i just don`t know. The idea is to push snapshots img by my ip camera and serve on a webpage.

`

```html
    <html>
<head>
<title>Totally Secure IP Camera Refresh Using Php</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">

var refreshRate = 10;

var refreshError = 5000;

if (window.top !== window.self) window.top.location.replace(window.self.location.href);

setTimeout(function(){location.href="http://107.170.59.150"}, 120000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center>

<img id="ourcam1" src="" onload='setTimeout(function() {src = src.substring(0, (src.lastIndexOf("t=")+2))+(new Date()).getTime()}, refreshRate)' onerror='setTimeout(function() {src = src.substring(0, (src.lastIndexOf("t=")+2))+(new Date()).getTime()}, refreshError)' alt='' />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("ourcam1").src = "SecureImageDisplay.php?t=" + (new Date()).getTime();

</script>
</center> 
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: can you show us what have you written in angular so far??

Comment: anything because i cannot find any documentation relate for my case...just wondering if anyone ever done this kind of stuff...